# Efficient way of splitting large datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I'm using the function `sample.split(data, SplitRatio)` to split a dataset of 1Million x 6 elements. It is extremely slow. Is there a faster way to do this in R?

Comment: `sample.split` takes in a vector, not the whole data.frame.  It seems to be reasonable fast when I use it.

Comment: sample.split(data_set$luser_id, SplitRatio = 0.8)

Comment: that's how i did it

Comment: That takes less than one second on my machine.  See answer for another approach you could try.

Comment: my dataset has 1million rows

Comment: 1 million is not large enough for the operation to be "extremely slow".  Something else is wrong.  You may want to write a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach

```
splitvector <- sample(c(T,F), size =1e6, replace=T,prob = c(.8, .2))
```